# count the nodes ignoring blank nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

**Case 1**

```
<body>
    <nd>
        <pnn>1.1</pnn>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <ti>Construction</ti>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>I INTRODUCT</h2>
        <ti>Time</ti>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>I INTRODUCT</h2>
        <ti>Power</ti>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>II APPLICATIONS</h2>
        <ti>Filing</ti>
    </nd>
</body>
```

**Case 2**

```
<body>
    <nd>
        <pnn>1.1</pnn>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>I INTRODUCT</h2>
        <ti>Construction</ti>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>I INTRODUCT</h2>
        <ti>Time</ti>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>II APPLICATIONS</h2>
        <ti>Filing</ti>
    </nd>
</body>
```

and the below XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="body"></xsl:apply-templates>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
         <xsl:for-each select="nd">
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="pnn"/>
   <xsl:template match="h1"/>
   <xsl:template match="h2"/>
   <xsl:template match="ti"/>
<xsl:variable name="FinalChap">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before((//pnn)[1],'.')"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="FinalChn">
        <xsl:value-of select="$FinalChap"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Finalchapternumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($FinalChn,'00')"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template name="section" match="nd">
        <xsl:variable name="count">
            <xsl:number count="nd" level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="classname">
            <!--Get name attribute of current node -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('section-sect','1')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="classname1">
            <!--Get name attribute of current node -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('section-sect','2')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="classname2">
            <!--Get name attribute of current node -->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('section-sect','3')"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!--Create a string variable by concat string method  -->
        <xsl:variable name="sectionname">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('CH_',$Finalchapternumber,'-SEC-', $count)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
            <div class="{$classname}">
            <xsl:if test="./h2 and not(preceding::h2[1]/text() = ./h2/text())">
                <a name="{$sectionname}"> </a>
                <div class="section-title">
                    <xsl:if test="not(preceding::h2[1]/text() = ./h2/text())">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="h2" mode="section"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not(lower-case(./ti/text()) = lower-case(./h2/text()))">
                <xsl:if test="./ti">
                    <div class="{$classname2}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ti" mode="section"/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::h2|self::ti)]"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ti" mode="section">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
        <xsl:variable name="sectionnum">
            <xsl:number count="nd" level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <a name="CH_{$Finalchapternumber}-SEC-{$sectionnum}"/>
        <div class="section-title">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="h2" mode="section">
        <div class="section-title">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::fnt)]"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:transform>
```

here I'm trying to increment the section number based on a condition. The count should be done, if there is no node(here `h2`) `<a name="CH_01-SEC-XX"></a>` should be ignored I'm able to do it using `<xsl:if test="./h2 and not(preceding::h2[1]/text() = ./h2/text())">`, but the challenge i'm facing is `count` is not ignoring it.

**Current output. Case 1**

```
<div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_01-SEC-1"/>
    <div class="section-title">
        <div class="section-title">I INTRODUCT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-1"/>
        <div class="section-title">Construction</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-2"/>
        <div class="section-title">Time</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-3"/>
        <div class="section-title">Power</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_01-SEC-4"/>
    <div class="section-title">
        <div class="section-title">II APPLICATIONS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-4"/>
        <div class="section-title">Filing</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Expected output Case 1**

```
<div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_01-SEC-1"/>
    <div class="section-title">
        <div class="section-title">I INTRODUCT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-2"/>
        <div class="section-title">Construction</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-3"/>
        <div class="section-title">Time</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-4"/>
        <div class="section-title">Power</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_01-SEC-5"/>
    <div class="section-title">
        <div class="section-title">II APPLICATIONS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-6"/>
        <div class="section-title">Filing</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current Output Case 2**

```
<div class="section-sect1"><a name="CH_01-SEC-1"></a><div class="section-title">
         <div class="section-title">I INTRODUCT</div>
      </div>
      <div class="section-sect3"><a name="CH_01-SEC-1"></a><div class="section-title">Construction</div>
      </div>
      </div>
   <div class="section-sect1">
      <div class="section-sect3"><a name="CH_01-SEC-2"></a><div class="section-title">Time</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section-sect1"><a name="CH_01-SEC-3"></a><div class="section-title">
         <div class="section-title">II APPLICATIONS</div>
      </div>
      <div class="section-sect3"><a name="CH_01-SEC-3"></a><div class="section-title">Filing</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**Expected output Case 2**

```
<div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_01-SEC-1"/>
    <div class="section-title">
        <div class="section-title">I INTRODUCT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-2"/>
        <div class="section-title">Construction</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-3"/>
        <div class="section-title">Time</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_01-SEC-4"/>
    <div class="section-title">
        <div class="section-title">II APPLICATIONS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-5"/>
        <div class="section-title">Filing</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in current output there is duplicate `CH_01-SEC-1` Can someone please let me know how to make it into a series of `1...n`

Here is a working [DEmo](http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqE/2)

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Why do you count the `nd, ti, h2`? If you change both `<xsl:number>` to `<xsl:number count="nd" />` it works fine. Is your sample XML significant enough? There's no `<a name="CH_01-SEC-XX"></a>` in the input, it is only present in output.

Comment: @potame, that is generated from `<xsl:variable name="sectionname">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('CH_',$Finalchapternumber,'-SEC-', $count)"/>
        </xsl:variable>`

Comment: Yes I've seen that, but it does not answer my questions :)

Comment: Hi @potame, I've updated my question with a different case, with same XSLT and changed count to count `nd` only, but here there are duplicates found instead of series. Also updated the demo link

Comment: I am afraid your question is still not clear. I suggest you minimize the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, the question is `count ti | h2` and the condition is, if `./h2/text() = preceding::h2[1]/text()`, `h2` should be ignored, and also if `./h2/text()=./ti/text()`, `ti` should be ignored, the count should be in sequence.

Comment: A minor stylistic point: don't write `<xsl:variable name="x"><xsl:value-of select="X"/></xsl:variable>` when you could write `<xsl:variable name="x" select="X"/>`. It's not just a matter of brevity: if you want your variable to be a string, it's horribly wasteful to create a tree with a document node and a text node, just so the document can be converted to a string whenever it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ....

```
<xsl:transform
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="FinalChap">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number( xs:integer( substring-before((/body/nd/pnn)[1],'.')), '00')"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head><title>New Version from Sean!</title></head>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|processing-instruction()|comment()|@*" />

<xsl:template match="body">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="nd" group-adjacent="h2/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="group-position" select="position()" />
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
     <xsl:call-template name="nd">
      <xsl:with-param name="group-position" select="$group-position" />
      <xsl:with-param name="is-head" select="position() eq 1" as="xs:boolean" />
     </xsl:call-template>  
    </xsl:for-each>  
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="nd">
 <xsl:param name="group-position" select="1" as="xs:integer" />
 <xsl:param name="is-head" select="true()" as="xs:boolean" />

 <div class="section-sect1">
  <xsl:if test="$is-head"> 
   <xsl:call-template name="a-link">
    <xsl:with-param name="group-position" select="$group-position" />
    <xsl:with-param name="delta" select="0" as="xs:integer" />
   </xsl:call-template>  
   <div class="section-title">
    <div class="section-title"><xsl:value-of select="h2" /></div>
   </div>
   </xsl:if>  
  <div class="section-sect3">
    <xsl:call-template name="a-link">
     <xsl:with-param name="group-position" select="$group-position" />
     <xsl:with-param name="delta" select="1" as="xs:integer" />
    </xsl:call-template>  
    <div class="section-title"><xsl:value-of select="ti" /></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="a-link">
 <xsl:param name="group-position" select="1" as="xs:integer" />
 <xsl:param name="delta" select="0" as="xs:integer" />
  <a name="CH_{$FinalChap}-SEC-{$group-position + count(preceding-sibling::nd) + $delta}" /> 
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:transform>
```

The above transform, when applied to input document ...

```
<body>
    <nd>
        <pnn>1.1</pnn>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>I INTRODUCT</h2>
        <ti>Construction</ti>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>I INTRODUCT</h2>
        <ti>Time</ti>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>I INTRODUCT</h2>
        <ti>Power</ti>
    </nd>
    <nd>
        <h1>PART 54</h1>
        <h2>II APPLICATIONS</h2>
        <ti>Filing</ti>
    </nd>
</body>
```

... yields output document ...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>New Version from Sean!</title>
</head>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_01-SEC-1"/>
    <div class="section-title">
        <div class="section-title">I INTRODUCT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-2"/>
        <div class="section-title">Construction</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-3"/>
        <div class="section-title">Time</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-4"/>
        <div class="section-title">Power</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-sect1">
    <a name="CH_01-SEC-5"/>
    <div class="section-title">
        <div class="section-title">II APPLICATIONS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect3">
        <a name="CH_01-SEC-6"/>
        <div class="section-title">Filing</div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

### Explanation

The `body` template uses the xsl:for-each-group to group the nd elements by common adjacent `h2` (h2 headings). The xsl:for-each-group sequence constructor invokes the `nd` template to process each `nd` element in order, passing to it the group number, and whether or not this `nd` is the first (the 'head') nd of the group.

I have inferred from your sample output, that the head `nd` of each group produces extra content being about the group, including an extra a-link.

The number of the a-link (for example 4 in `CH_01-SEC-4`) is equal to the count of preceding nd's, plus the group number, plus an extra 1 if we are not a head nd.

### Alternative solutions

Just as there are many ways to skin a cat, there a quiet a few alternative solutions which would be equally valid. Instead of grouping, you could use a full push design. The extra content for head nodes (`<div class="section-title">`) could be achieved using a predicate on the template pattern, comparing this h2 with the previous h2. And the correcting number of the a-links could be achieved by micro-pipelining.

Comment: Hi Friend, Thanks for the solution, This worked great, but when trying to run the same with another XML, This is throwing some error, in second XML, there are `h2` randomly, i.e. not present in all `nd`, I've updated my question, can you please help me with this, here i removed `h2` in first `nd` block. Sorry not for providing in starting itself

Comment: @user3872094: Could you update the question to provide both test cases? A test case is a sample input document together with its expected output document.

Comment: Hi Friend, Updated my question with both the cases. aolng with current and expected output

Comment: @user3872094: I ran both test cases with the given solution, and both produced 100% correct output. I used http://fiddle.frameless.io/ for testing. There is no error. I suggest that you re-test. You may have made a typographical error and not noticed.

Or perhaps there is a third test case you need to show? The supplied two test cases both work.